# Convert html from Wordpress API (Elementor) in vue.js/nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, wordpress-rest-api, elementor

So I have been using elementor for my wordpress blog. Then with the help of Wordpress API the content that is rendered is sent to Vue and is rendered by "v-html" attribute.
My problem is that the rendered HTML I get from Wordpress API have classes from elementor and Vue doesn't know what to do with those CSS classes. Is there a way for my Vue app to know the CSS classes that elementor is making.
Example blog in Vue app :- https://www.edhusk.com/blog/black-holes

Comment: Hi, did you find a way to make it work with elementor